# Twitter bootstrap's jquery plug-ins don't work after I modified bootstrap.css

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I modified bootstrap.css using LESS so I can use Bootstrap only inside of a <div class="tw-bs"></div> element. Here is my bootstrap.css:
http://pastebin.com/68yRSc1u

Now I'm trying to use tooltips and modals with the following code:
http://pastebin.com/GBFYN6U2

However, nor modals, neither tooltips don't work.

Please advice!

Comment: In the pastebin, your jquery and boostrap.js includes point to localhost, while bootstrap.css points to another host. Are you sure your JS is being included correctly?

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili, it's just an example for a web. Fixed. Problem still exists.

Comment: @Spoike, nope. Only warnings.

Comment: What warnings do you get from your "real" problem?

Comment: @Spoike Absolutely same warnings even if I use native bootstrap.css & bootstrap.js so I don't think it's important in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the paths to your js files are correct, 
Changing all of the CSS makes the coding for the modals and tooltips broken because their appended to the body, document, or the parent of its element. If you need to have the `tw-bs` class on everything, I'd recommend trying to put it on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag first, if that doesnt work then taking out the `.tw-bs` before all `.modal`, `.popover`, `.tooltip`, `.carousel`, and `.collapse' classes in CSS to fix it. Some of these classes are set within the JS file

and to get the tooltips to work you would do

```
$(function(){
  $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Comment: I decided to use standard bootstrap.css because of too many problems, but your hint for a tooltip is really useful. Thanks!